# Best way to do a looping move effect in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, effects, move

I want to display an animated arrow that goes back and forth (using flex 4).  I'm using the following move effect :

```
<s:Move id="animateArrow" target="{arrow}" duration="750" repeatCount="0" repeatBehavior="reverse" yFrom="{arrow.y}" yTo="{arrow.y - 25}"/>
```

When needed, I then play the effect:
    animateArrow.end();
    animateArrow.play();

The animation works as intended but it seems to be a huge resource hog while playing.  Any logic that happens while playing the animateArrow effect takes a very long time to load.  Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any effect will take resources.  If it's taking more cpu than anticipated, you might want to look at the object you're moving, it's container, and the code it might affect.

Personally, I wouldn't use Adobe's animation library as they aren't very optimized.  I would look at [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) instead.

Comment: Thanks, will check out TweenMax